# Multiple Conditional Validators Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an update form for users with an optional input for password changes that once the user fills in should have the necessary validation. So for example if the user enters a password into the password input the form should have validation on the confirm password input i.e confirm password needs to become a required field and it needs to match the password input. However I am struggling to have both required and pattern validators conditionally, what I mean by this is that if I have a pattern validation then the required validation stops being set and if I remove pattern validation then the required validation will work.

Here is my conditional validation code:

```
this.password?.valueChanges
  // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
  .subscribe(inputValue => {
    const confirmPassword = this.confirmPassword;
    if (inputValue !== '') {
      confirmPassword?.setValidators(Validators.required);
      confirmPassword?.setValidators(Validators.pattern(inputValue));
    } else {
      confirmPassword?.clearValidators();
    }
    confirmPassword?.updateValueAndValidity();
  });
```

Here is my HTML error code:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="confirmPassword?.invalid">
  <div *ngIf="confirmPassword?.errors?.required">
     Fine then. Keep your secrets.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="confirmPassword?.errors?.pattern">
     Your passwords need to match!
  </div>
</mat-error>
```

Answer:

The validators were overwriting you need to set them like so to prevent this.

```
confirmPassword?.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(inputValue)]);
```